# not able to connect to 3307 running on mysql using terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

I have two instance of mysql running on server. i.e on port 3306 and other on 3307

I remote login to my server using ssh.

After login using sudo user when i try to connect to mysql server running on 3307, but it takes me to instance running on 3306

Commands which i tried for mysql login.

```
mysql --port=3307
```

After login in i run the below command

```
mysql> show variables like '%port%';
```

I get the below output.

```
+---------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name       | Value          |
+---------------------+----------------+
| extra_port          | 0              |
| innodb_support_xa   | ON             |
| large_files_support | ON             |
| port                | 3306           |
| report_host         | 192.168.XX.XXX |
| report_password     |                |
| report_port         | 3306           |
| report_user         |                |
+---------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help

**EDIT**

```
 netstat -tlnap |grep mysql
```

Output of above command.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      23788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::3307                 :::*                    LISTEN      28934/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 192.168.XX.XXX:3306     172.29.XXX.XXX:61548    ESTABLISHED 23788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 192.168.XX.XXX:3306     172.29.XXX.XXX:62479    ESTABLISHED 23788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 192.168.XX.XXX:3306     172.29.XXX.XXX:62334    ESTABLISHED 23788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 192.168.XX.XX:3306     172.29.XXX.XXX:62390    ESTABLISHED 23788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 192.168.XX.XXX:3306     172.29.XXX.XXX:62529    ESTABLISHED 23788/mysqld
```

Comment: paste the output - `netstat -tlnap |grep mysql`

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam please find the output in question.

Comment: try- `mysql --port=3307  -h localhost`

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: once try by changing bind ip(system's local ip) for mysql 3307